# Primefaces datatable: partial processing on row selection

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a primefaces datatable with ajax events to handle multiple row selection. Within the table I also have some in-place editing components. The problem is that whenever I select a row, the whole table gets processed, including the input components.

Is there a way to only process the row selections, not the inputs?

example xhtml...

```
<p:dataTable value="#{controller.data}" var="d" rowKey="#{d.id}"
             selection="#{controller.selected}" rowSelectMode="add">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" partialSubmit="true" process="@this"
            update=":anotherComponent"/>
    <!-- ...and other events -->

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>

    <p:column>
        <p:inplace editor="true" saveLabel="Apply changes" >
            <p:inputText value="#{d.value}"/>
            <p:ajax event="save" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" 
                    listener="#{controller.saveChanges(d)}"/>
        </p:inplace>
    </p:column>

    <!-- ...and other columns -->
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no official way to do this. I reported this to the PF team a half year ago and they promised that they will introduce something like `process="@onlyThis"`, but there is no ETA for this enhancement.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I've worked around it just by making sure my app expects these extras to be submitted